# forming confidence ellipse versus using contrast

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

Suppose I am testing a hypothesis on data that is bivariate normal, $(x,y)\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is known but $\mu$ is not. My null hypothesis is a contrast $a^T\mu=a_1\mu_1+a_2\mu_2=0$. The data gives me $(\bar x,\bar y)\sim N(\mu,\Sigma/n)$. I'm trying to understand the relationship between two testing strategies:

1. Since $a^T(\bar x,\bar y)\sim N(a^T\mu,a^T\Sigma a/n),$ test the z-statistic $$\frac{a^T(\bar x,\bar y)-a^T\mu}{\sqrt{a^T\Sigma a/n}}$$
   if it exceeds $z_\alpha$.
2. Since $(\bar x,\bar y)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\bar x,\bar y)/n$ is chi-squared with 2 degrees of freedom, I could form a confidence ellipse in the $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ plane with center at $(\bar x, \bar y)$ with the size determined by a chi-squared quantile, and see if it includes the line given by the contrast, $a^T\mu=0$.

Are these equivalent tests? Is the second even a valid test of the contrast?

Comment: No ellipse wholly includes *any* line.  This makes it difficult to understand what you mean by (2).

Comment: @whuber I meant intersects the line. So there would be points in the null hypothesis set that are compatible with the data in that they lie in the confidence ellipse, then don't reject that null.

Comment: I was hoping that formulating such a description of the situation would make it clear to you that the second approach is invalid and show how to reconcile it with the first one.  Maybe it would help to rephrase your description of "intersects the line" as "projects to an interval in the subspace generated by the contrast."

Comment: @whuber but wouldn't the projection of an ellipse onto a line be an interval whether or not the line intersects the ellipse?

Comment: The interval is determined by the width of the ellipse perpendicular to the line direction.

Comment: Looks to me like a multiple comparisons problem. As such, the first approach is invalid because there is no multiplicity correction. The second approach, when tidied up, looks like the Working-Hotelling approach, which is valid.

Comment: @BigBendRegion Where are the multiple comparisons?  A single hypothesis is being tested.  When appropriate coordinates are chosen, this problem is equivalent to the univariate case of testing $\mu=0$ using a sample from a (scalar) Normal$(\mu,1)$ distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to analyze this distribution a little, because it reduces the situation to a familiar one with a clear answer.

Upon setting

$$z=a_1x + a_2 y = \pmatrix{a_1,&a_2}\pmatrix{x\\y} = \mathbf a^\prime \pmatrix{x\\y},$$

compute the moments of this linear combination of the bivariate Normal random variable $(x,y)^\prime$ as

$$E[z] = a_1E[x]+a_2E[y] = a_1\mu_1 + a_2 \mu_2$$

and

$$\operatorname{Var}(z) = \pmatrix{a_1,&a_2}\Sigma\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2} = \mathbf a^\prime \Sigma \mathbf a = \sigma^2$$

(thereby defining $\sigma^2$).

Consequently, $z$ has a Normal distribution with known variance and your null hypothesis can be expressed as $H_0: E[z]=0.$  **Test this in the usual way with a Z test.**  The test statistic is

$$Z = \frac{\bar z}{\operatorname{SE}(\bar z)} = \frac{a_1\bar x + a_2\bar y}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}= \frac{\mathbf a^\prime (\bar x,\bar y)^\prime}{\sqrt{\mathbf a^\prime \Sigma \mathbf a\,/n}}.$$

I believe this is what (1) in the question is intended to say.  (Notice that $\mu$ *cannot* appear anywhere in the statistic because it is unknown.)  Because the alternative hypothesis is $E[z]\ne 0,$ the critical region is where $|Z|\gt Z_{\alpha/2}$ where $Z_{\alpha/2}$ is the $100(1-\alpha/2)$ percentile of the standard Normal distribution.

In response to a comment to the question, this is a single test making a single comparison and therefore needs no adjustment for multiple comparisons.

---

The problem with (2) in the question is that, by constructing a critical region in the $(\bar x, \bar y)$ plane, *it involves an independent random variable;* namely, another linear combination of $(\bar x, \bar y)$ that is uncorrelated with $\bar z.$  Using the confidence region approach effectively balances the potential for decision errors in the test you are interested in against decision errors involving this unrelated variable and therefore cannot be any better.